# Rails - Using Autocomplete with the Scoped_search gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, autocomplete

I'm using the `scoped_search` gem for basic search functionality on my site.  Scoped search: http://github.com/wvanbergen/scoped_search

I'm using the most basic possible implementation of this gem. I'm searching on the name attribute in a user model only.  On the frontend, in users/index, the search input is a `text_field_tag.`

```
<% form_tag users_path, :method => :get do %>  
    <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], :value => 'Search' %>
    <%= submit_tag "Go", :name => nil %>
<%end%>
```

In the user model, I have:

```
scoped_search :on => :name
```

I want to implement basic auto-complete functionality on the user model, name attribute. This would be the most basic use case if I was searching in a form element of the user model, but the `scoped_search` part is throwing me off.

I was planning to use DHH's auto_complete plugin, but I'm open to using whatever tool helps me accomplish this.
Auto-complete: http://github.com/rails/auto_complete

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

- In the model you should replace the
  line:

  scoped_search :on => :name

with:

```
scoped_search :on => :name, :complete_value => true
```

- In the view replace the line:

  <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], :value => 'Search' %>

with:

```
<%= auto_complete_field_tag_jquery(:search, params[:search], {},{}) %>
```

- In the controller you should add the following method:

  def auto_complete_search

  @items = User.complete_for(params[:search])

  render :json => @items

  end

Answer (score 0):

did you see the demo app at https://github.com/abenari/scoped_search_demo_app ?

Alternatively, you can see how I use it in my project - https://github.com/ohadlevy/foreman

Ohad